# How to enter strings in sentences in scanf without duplicating into next scanf? C programming

Tags: c

So I'm trying to get a `scanf` to accept strings and store it which will not carry into the next `scanf`. I'm quite new to C.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char word1[100];
    char word2[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&word1);
    printf("Enter a second sentence:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&word2);
    printf("%s %s",word1,word2);

    return 0;
}
```

But it'll display this:

```
Enter a sentence:I am 
Enter a second sentence:I am P)Γ
Press Enter to return to Quincy...
```

What I want it to display is:

```
Enter a sentence:I am
Enter a second sentence: bread !
I am bread!
```

Any advice?

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` is wrong. When you specify a *character class* (e.g. `[...]`) you do NOT follow with a `'s'`. Further, a character class does not skip leading whitespace, so you will need to remove the `'\n'` that remains in your input buffer before your second input or you will suffer an input failure as the read terminates on the `'\n'` without any character read. `"%99[^\n]%*c"` would work -- and check the return to validate the conversion. (which is why new C programmers are encouraged to use `fgets` of POSIX `getline` for line oriented input as they consume the trialing newline.)

Comment: Take a look at [I need a explanation of fscanf parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165131/i-need-a-explanation-of-fscanf-parameter) answered just a few minutes ago for further explanation.

Comment: If you want to read a line, why not use a function that reads lines?

Comment: That's always the great mystery for new C programmers, why use a *formatted input* function to do *line oriented input*...

Comment: If obliged to use `scanf()`, to well use it, you need to defined what should happen 1) when a line of user input consists of only a `"\n"` and 2) what should code do if more than 99 characters entered?   else the question is too broad.

Comment: Any advice? --> Always check the return value from input functions and  do not use `scanf()`.  Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a escaping "\" inside a string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char word1[100];
char word2[100];
printf("Enter a sentence:");
scanf("%[^\\n]s",&word1);
printf("Enter a second sentence:");
scanf("%[^\\n]s",&word2);
printf("%s %s",word1,word2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you specify a *character class* (e.g. `[...]`) you do NOT follow with a `'s'`... and you do NOT need to escape within the character class, not on Unix and not on Windoze.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues

1. Use `"%[^\n]%*c"`.
2. use `word1` and not `&word1`.

   ```
   //test.c
   #include < stdio.h >
   #include < stdlib.h >

   int main(){

       char word1[100];
       char word2[100];
       printf("Enter a sentence:");
       scanf("%[^\n]%*c",word1);
       printf("Enter a second sentence:");
       scanf("%[^\n]%*c",word2);
       printf("%s %s",word1,word2);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Add 4-spaces before your code to format properly `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin. Thank You

Comment: Sure. Now if you check the return of `scanf` (e.g. `if (scanf ("%99[^\n]%*c",word1) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`) it would really start looking good. (you must check the return of every call to `scanf`, and as a bonus trap the manually generated `EOF` separately `:)`

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",word1);` has 2 short-comings: If the first character is a `'\n'`, `word1` is unchanged and `printf("%s %s",word1,word2);` is undefined behavior.  2) if more than 99 characters read, `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",word1);` will overflow `word1[]` and more undefined behavior.   Consider `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){

    char word1[100];
    char word2[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&word1);

    getchar(); // clear the "\n" from stdin

    printf("Enter a second sentence:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&word2);
    printf("%s %s",word1,word2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` is not needed.